# Fitnesse execute too many tests

Tags: java, testing, fitnesse

I just wrote my first fitnesse test. This test is executed with the help of fitnesse runner. My project contains 1 fitnesse test. This test itself succeeds, but when start the test fitnesse seemse to execute the test twice. The second test fails.

```
Failed tests:
fitnesse.RunLoginFT at least one test executed in LoginTest
0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions

Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I ran the next test:

```
@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)
@FitNesseRunner.Suite("LoginTest")
@FitNesseRunner.FitnesseDir("./src/test/resources")
@FitNesseRunner.OutputDir("target/fitnesse")
public class RunLoginFT {

}
```

My test scenario looks like:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
|import|
|nl.belastingdienst.jos.cta.pipeline.kantoor.functioneletests.fitnesse|

|script|login test|
|open|!-https://localhost:9443/url-!|
|enter|XXXX|as|j_username|
|enter|XXXX|as|j_password|
|click|submit|
|check field exists|testknop|
```

---

```
public class LoginTest {

private WebDriver driver;

public void open(String siteUrl) {
    driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(siteUrl);
}

public void enterAs(String value, String place) {
    driver.findElement(By.id(place)).sendKeys(value);
}

public void click(String button) {
    driver.findElement(By.id(button)).click();
}

public void checkFieldExists(String fieldName) {
    // Als het element niet gevonden kan worden treed eer een exception op dus assert is niet
    // nodig
    driver.findElement(By.id(fieldName));
}
```

}

Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: Does the test contain any assertions (i.e. cells that go green)? Can you share the test's content? Is anything created in output directory?

Comment: @FriedHoeben I've added some extra info to the Original quiestion. On the result page the import line is green and the script name

Comment: Looking at your fixture code, may I suggest you look at existing standard fixtures working with selenium http://www.fitnesse.org/PlugIns#slimfixtures. And, of course, mine in particular browser test  in https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test has no assertions.

Make one if your methods return a boolean. Or make the check method return an actual value and use script table's check keyword to compare that actual to an expected value.

Comment: returning a boolean solves the issue. Gonna dive deaper into the other solution as well!